# Manejo de Archivo CSV en C++ y que realice operaciones

Tags: c++, c++11, dev-c++

Estaba haciendo un programa que lee un archivo Csv , en su interior aparece una lista de nits, fecha y cantidad gastada y que una vez guardada esa información el programa tendría que calcular lo siguiente:

- Sumatoria NITs.
- La Media NITs.
- El NIT Mínimo.
- El NIT Máximo.

Mi programa ya suma los nits que estan repetidos en el archivo CSV, pero aun me falta sumar todas las cantidades gastadas , y sacar la media, el nit máximo , y mínimo, me ayude con un libro pero la verdad no logro hacer esa parte.
Cualquier ayuda se los agradecería , Uso code block pero tengo habilitado la opción::: Have g++ follow the c++11 Iso C++ language standard [-std=c++11]

Así está mi programa, esto muestra actualmente:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mi programa tiene que mostrar esta información:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El archivo CSV tiene 1000 registros, más o menos está así:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <map>

void leer();

class Dato{
public:
    long nit;
    std::string fecha;
    double total;
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Dato& obj);
};

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Dato& objeto)
{
    os << "nit: " << objeto.nit << ", fecha: " << objeto.fecha << ", total: " << objeto.total;
}

int main()
{
    leer();
    return 0;
}

void leer()
{
    std::string nombre;
    std::ifstream infile("archivo.csv");
    std::string line;
    std::vector<Dato *> datos_csv;
    std::map<long, double> sumados;
    std::map<long, double>::iterator buscaSumados;
    while (getline(infile, line)) {
        std::stringstream strstr(line);
        std::string word;
        Dato *actual = new Dato();
        for (int indice = 0; getline(strstr, word, ','); indice++) {
            switch(indice) {
            case 0:
                actual->nit = std::stol(word);
                break;
            case 1:
                actual->fecha = word;
                break;
            case 2:
                actual->total = std::stod(word);
                break;
           }
        }

        datos_csv.push_back(actual);
        buscaSumados = sumados.find(actual->nit);

        if (buscaSumados == sumados.end()) {
            sumados.insert(std::pair<long, double>(actual->nit, actual->total));
        }
        else
        {
            buscaSumados->second += actual->total;
        }
    }

    system("color f0");
        std::cout<< "\n\n";
        std::cout<< "\t  TOTAL NIT" << "         " << "TOTAL GASTADO";
        std::cout<< "\n\n";

        for (std::map<long, double>::iterator i = sumados.begin(); i != sumados.end(); i++) {
            std::cout<< ""<< "\t NIT: " << i->first << ",  GASTADO: " << i->second << std::endl;
        }
}
```

Comment: Marco la pregunta como duplicada porque el total se te suma correctamente y la única diferencia que veo está en la presentación de los datos... problema que ya está solucionado en la otra pregunta

Comment: Bro , fijate que la pregunta con la que asociaste, lo que pregunte esta erronea.
Porque en el aterior post preguntan sobre como sacar punto decimal y mostrar las comas 

En cambio yo estoy preguntando como, poder sacar la suma , el media , el mayor y el menor numero gastado.